# Problem in definition of newcommand with optional argument

Tags: macros, document-classes, optional-arguments

I'm trying to define a newcommand in a `.cls` file as follows:

```
\newcommand{\test}[2][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\raggedright\itshape{#2}}%
    {\raggedright#1 \hfill \itshape{#2}}%
}
```

However, this gives `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`. I have included the package `xifthen` with `\RequirePackage{xifthen}`. I should also mention that if one removes the `[]`, which is intended for the optional argument, the code seems to work just fine.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: here's the main part of the class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{my_class}[2020/07/31 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\newenvironment{myenv}%
    {\addvspace{0.1in}\noindent\ignorespaces}
    {\par\noindent%\addvspace{0.1in}
    \ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\first}[2]{%
    {\begingroup \raggedright \textbf{#1} \hfill \textit{#2} \newline \endgroup}%
}

\newcommand{\second}[2][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\textit{\raggedleft #2} \newline}%
    {\begingroup \raggedright #1 \hfill \textit{#2} \newline \endgroup}%
}
```

and here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{my_class}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{myenv}
    \first{This is bold text}{This is italic text}
    \second[Optional argument given]{This is italic text}
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
    \first{Bold text}{Italic text}
    \second{Optional argument omitted}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

When `\second` is provided with the optional argument, it seems to work fine, outputting the first argument to the left and the second to the right of the same line. However, when the optional argument is not provided, the second argument is written as if were left-justified, not right-justified (which is what I want). I used groups to limit the the effects of the switches such as `\raggedright` but I don't think I did it right.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this approach. I do prefer [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse?lang=en) when defining commands with optional arguments, because it provides more tools for customization. (See this [document](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-xparse.pdf) for more info.)

Comment: Maybe an incompatibility with some other part of your .cls file? This code, inserted as an ordinay macro in a preamble, works fine.

Comment: This won't produce the error, by itself. Probably the context in which you use it is the problem. However this is not particularly good: using the command will continue ragged right and italic type forever.

Comment: To expand on what @egreg said: this isn’t the source of your error, but you probably meant `\textit{\raggedright {#1}}` instead of `\raggedright\itshape`.

Comment: To solve this problem, we would need a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that reproduces the bug. It’s in some part of the code that you didn’t post.

Comment: Thanks to all that replied. I edited my question and added code from the class file and a minimal working example.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace somewhere. Please post a _minimal_ and _complete_ example, not snippets which we must paste together.

Comment: I added the missing brace. These are not snippets though... this is the code I have. The only thing missing is the opening part of the class file, which I'll post for completeness' sake.

Comment: Your posted example cannot reproduce the problem. Normally error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` is raised when you typeset text in a list-like environment before first `\item`.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been clearer. That issue is gone, but the code does not behave the way I would like. The explanation of the intended behaviour is in the last part of the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the aim of the code, but there are several things that are superfluous.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myenv}
    {\par\addvspace{0.1in}}
    {\par\addvspace{0.1in}}
\newcommand{\first}[2]{%
    {\raggedright\textbf{#1}\hfill\textit{#2}\par}%
}
\newcommand{\second}[2][]{%
    {\raggedright#1\hfill\textit{#2}\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{myenv}
    \first{This is bold text}{This is italic text}
    \second[Optional argument given]{This is italic text}
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
    \first{Bold text}{Italic text}
    \second{Optional argument omitted}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\newline` is out of place and would produce warnings. However, your code doesn't show the mentioned error in my experiment.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!